# How can I run javax.validations and Spring Validation together with validate method call?

Tags: java, spring, validation, spring-mvc

I am using javax.validation annotations for constraints on my POJO. Also, I have written a custom validator using spring validator. How can I validate a nested object with both javax.validations and spring validations.

For example:

```
ObjectA - Uses javax.validations. Ex: @NotNull
ObjectA contains List of ObjectB. 

ObjectB - Uses custom spring validations.
```

I would like to check if ObjectA is valid or not, which in turn run the custom spring validations for ObjectB.